# Bring gh-pages up to date with the latest commit of master

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree in combination with a Github repository for version control for a project. For a while, I've been using `master` to commit all new changes, but every now and then, I want the `gh-pages` branch to fast-forward to the latest commit of `master`, so that I can update the live page with the page I have in production (usually when a major update is finished).

I have tried rebasing, as another SO post suggested, but this made the problem even worse, as SourceTree had me manually choose what changes I wanted and the rebasing took a little while especially considering the amount of commits between the last update of `gh-pages`. After successfully rebasing in one project, I could basically sync the `gh-pages` branch to `master` whenever I desired and all in-between versions would commit automatically (I could not reproduce the same behavior in another repository though). However, what I want is to get the last commit and overwrite all files. To do this, I usually just copy the whole folder while on `master` branch to another location, then switch to `gh-pages` and overwrite all files manually. This is sub-optimal, though and can get really problematic for larger projects.

So, what I want and need is to automate this procedure, either through SourceTree or via a script.

**TL;DR**: I need a way to update `gh-pages` to the latest `master` commit semi-automatically, which will overwrite all files with the ones in `master` without rebasing and will then push them to the Github repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, what I want is to get the last commit and overwrite all files.

You should:

- merge `gh-pages` to `master` with the `--ours` option (so master is actually untouched).
- merge master to `gh-pages` (which means `gh-pages` fast-forwards to `master` and becomes identical)

So:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ours gh-pages
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
```

---

Don't forget though that since a few days ago, you don't have to maintain a `gh-pages` branch anymore.

**[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

Comment: Should I execute that sequence of commands while on `master` or while on `gh-pages`?

The idea of not maintaining a `gh-pages` branch sounds kind of nice for a change actually, as I can probably work on the rest of the page and the live version at the same time, without breaking anything. Thanks!

Comment: @AngelosChalaris That sequence of commands incudes setting the current branch. So you can start it from any branch (preferably in a clean workspace)

Comment: Right, thanks a whole lot for your answer and for showcasing this new feature!

Answer (score 0):

#### For those who have created their app with **create-react-app**.

> this was the **only** method that worked for me without errors

1. Add this snippet in your /public/index.html to solve the browsers caching issue

```html
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

2. change the default breach from **gh-pages** to **master** ([guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch#changing-the-default-branch))
3. delete gh-pages Branch Both Locally and Remotely ([guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/))
4. Run: `npm run deploy`. This will build your app and re-create gh-pages branch with updated content.
5. choose the  **gh-pages** branch as publishing source and the  **/(root)** as a folder for your publishing source.([guide](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source))
6. **It may take some time**. After a minute visit your site and it should be updated by now.

([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001847/9180698)).

*if you have an alternative please share!*