# project set up using github pages not loading

Tags: github-pages

I hosted one of my project using GitHub pages but, for some reason, when I access the URL the page doesn't loads, and when I check it in the dev console it shows this error.

[image: image of the error]

This is my GitHub page URL: https://prasunk96.github.io/colorsgame/

I checked that all the internal links that I have in my html file are all correct.
I have tried it several times but it showing the same problem again and again.

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two issues with your CSS link:

1. It is not relative to your html file so the browser is trying to go directly from the base `prasunk96.github.io/` and not include the `/colorsgame/`.
2. Github.io urls are case sensitive so your `colorGamepro.css` isn't being matched to the `ColorGamepro.css` file.

To correct the relative url you can either add a base tag to your HTML file or use a relative href. Once you correct the file name it should be able to find your file at https://prasunk96.github.io/colorsgame/css/ColorGamepro.css

**In short use:** `href="./css/ColorGamepro.css"`

Answer (score 1):

Github project pages can sometime take a bit before being updated. See "[My GitHub page won't update its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33218209/6309)" for a similar issue.

I do see (a few hours later) a 404 for your css:

[image: github project page loaded]
[image: 404]

Try and see if using an anchored url works better:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/colorGamepro.css">
                                            ^^^
                                             |
```