# Github pages does not display the changes

Tags: git, vue.js, webpack, github-pages

I a have Vue.js (`webpack`) project running on my Github pages. The problem is Github pages do not display the recent commit, Instead, it only displays the initial commit's content. what I'm doing is:

```
$ git commit -m "update"
$ git push origin master
```

then:

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ git rebase master
$ git push origin gh-pages
```

I see that the branches gets updates, but no content will be changed on my page.

I even tried deleting the gh-branch and recreate it again but it didn't solve the problem. I even deleted the browser cache.
Note that when I'm running the `dist` folder locally everything is ok.

[here](https://github.com/Msiavashi/wallthereum) is the link to the repo.

I sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem is my GitHub page do not update its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713112/problem-is-my-github-page-do-not-update-its-content)

Comment: I tried all the suggested solutions. none of them worked for me. @Ruturaj

Comment: I see you have three `index.html` in your repo.  Are you sure that you are updating the correct `index.html` here: https://github.com/Msiavashi/wallthereum/blob/gh-pages/index.html?  Maybe you are only updating the `index.html` in the `dist` folder?  https://github.com/Msiavashi/wallthereum/blob/gh-pages/dist/index.html

Comment: @Kin isn't github serve the dist folder?
however both dist, and source are changed when i run them localy.

Comment: @Mohammad Siavashi I am unfamiliar with the `dist` folder, so I am not sure.  Regardless, seems like changing the source `index.html` doesn't help unblock you.