# My github page doesn't seem to be updating at all

Tags: github, github-pages

I have tried all the possible solutions that are either mentioned on Github and on stack-overflow. But no matter what I do. It still shows me an old version of the page and doesn't update at all. Someone please help.

I have followed all the instructions in this [Problem is my GitHub page do not update its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713112/problem-is-my-github-page-do-not-update-its-content). Still no luck. Someone please help

Comment: Can you share the link of your page?

Comment: @Emre I was able to fix it today. Apparently it was getting double hosted. One from the forked site. And one from the github.io repo that I made. And the changes that I made to the github.io repo did not reflect on the web page. So once I made sure that the forked repo where it was being published was fixed the website updated in a few mins. 

Ps. my page diwakar-ravichandran.github.io