# Github pages not update when i was commit in master

Tags: github-pages

i have deploy react js on github pages, when i new commit there is no change in publish github pages [there is my publish pages](https://agilsaputra.github.io/web_ticket/) .

[new commit](https://github.com/agilsaputra/web_ticket/commit/5a7c939ec704bcf5dfa582e5a229ff0193da396f#diff-014c474f9332e70f0d56492e91e6feea0ce38b16c1e7f89f45d60248a4ed4469)

[my repository](https://github.com/agilsaputra/web_ticket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things can be behind this. In your case, I think it is about the branch you're using.

You are pushing to branch `master` while Github page is watching over `gh-page` branch.

More reasons can be found in answers to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713112/why-does-my-github-page-do-not-update-its-content).