# Deleted gh-pages branch

Tags: git, github, deployment, github-pages

I am having a problem where https://lindsayreiner.github.io (https://github.com/lindsayreiner/lindsayreiner.github.io) deployed portfolio page is not updating after pushing changes from my local branch.

I found this [Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713112/why-does-my-github-page-do-not-update-its-content) which describes my problem exactly but in an attempt to fix the issue I followed the advise in the 2nd answer by doing:

```
git push origin :gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages
```

which gave me an error that the `gh-pages` branch does not exist.

So now my deployment isn’t reflecting the code base in the repository and I don’t have a `gh-pages` branch.

How do I restore my `gh-pages` branch and get my deployment to be in line with the code in my repo?

I’ve tried updating my `index.html` file in the GitHub website prior to deleting the `gh-pages` branch and this did nothing, and I also cleared my cache and did a hard reload and that didn’t do anything either.

Comment: The trick here lies in finding the correct hash ID (SHA-1) of the commit. This is in effect the "true name" of the commit. GitHub never actually delete any commit at all, by default, so even removing all the human-oriented names like `gh-pages` that help Git *find* the hash ID doesn't matter ... *except* that now *you* need to find the hash ID. VonC's method is as good as or better than any other one I know. Ultimately you must find this hash ID; that's what a branch name like `gh-pages` is really about: how to find hash IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query the recent push events from your GitHub repository:

`curl -u "username:PersonalAccessToken" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"  https://api.github.com/repos/RepoOwner/Repo/events`

Replace `RepoOwner` and `Repo` with your GitHub account and repository name.

Look for a `DeleteEvent` with its matching SHA1, and try and fetch that (git fetch SHA1, replace SHA1 with the actual SHA value).

Then:

```
git switch -c gh_pages SHA1
git push -u origin gh_pages
```

Comment: I found the delete event but I don't see an SHA in that Delete Event object. I only see SHA's in the Push Event's.

Comment: @LindsayReiner Is there any PushEvent before that DeleteEvent, which would involve gh_pages?